# Ctrl + R not working for loopcut

Tags: shortcut

My problem is that Blender is not reading <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for loop cut, I can change the shortcut, but I want it to work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't working? Are you in edit mode inside a mesh object, and do you see the status bar displaying anything different after hitting Ctrl R ?

Comment: Nop, it doesn't do anything at all, however it works when I press the Loopcut icon, it just not reading that shortcut. ctrl key works fine with others key, like ctrl+B and ctrl+A, but not with R

Comment: do you have a keyboard layout that binds Ctrl R to something else than r ? are you able to create a functional shortcut for another operator with Ctrl R ?

Comment: Look up the [keybinding](https://imgur.com/a/Salqg4o) under Edit>Preferences>Keymap . and see if it's assigned.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if Ctrl R is bind to something else, and I can't assign ctrl r for another operator example, if I want to assign ctrl r as the shortcut for bevel it does not let me do it, also the weird thing is that ctrl r is assigned to loopcut in the key-binding, I also try to Load factory settings and it didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was a VPN app that installed itself called Reason Security and Safer web (both are the same vpn). If anyone gets the same problem check if you have a VPN installed. Some say if you have Torrent it also causes the problem. In my case I uninstalled it, but the problem persisted.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, it was related to a VPN application called "Rav VPN"